# How to remove numbers in a list of list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, arraylist

I have a dataframe and one of the columns is a list of lists. I want to remove numbers in that listoflist column. How can I do that?

```
mylist = [['302','is','my','apartment','number'],['I','wake','up','at','7','am'],['I','spent','10','dollars','for','lunch']]

[word for word in mylist if word.isalpha()]
```

I tried the above code but it returns "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isalpha'"

My expected result:

```
[['is','my','apartment','number'],['I','wake','up','at','am'],['I','spent','dollars','for','lunch']]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a nested list of comprehension to do so :

```
mylist = [['302','is','my','apartment','number'],['I','wake','up','at','7','am'],['I','spent','10','dollars','for','lunch']]

print([[word for word in arr if word.isalpha()] for arr in mylist])
```

**Output**

```
[['is', 'my', 'apartment', 'number'],
 ['I', 'wake', 'up', 'at', 'am'],
 ['I', 'spent', 'dollars', 'for', 'lunch']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to apply what you wrote to *each* list in `my list`.